# Dois domínios apontados para a mesma instancia ec2

Tags: apache, amazon-aws, virtualhost

Tenho dois domínios, abc.com.br e xyz.com.br. Estou apontando ambos para a mesma instância ec2 na Amazon. Tenho duas aplicações php (wordpress) dentro dessa instância, um que fica em /var/www/html e outra q fica em /var/www/html/xyz.

Não estou conseguindo configurar corretamente o httpd.conf para ao acessar através de abc.com.br acessar /var/www/html e xyz.com.br acessar o site em /var/www/html/xyz

Eu adicionei o seguinte código

```
<VirtualHost xyz.com.br:80>
    ServerAdmin email@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/xyz"
    ServerName xyz.com.br
    Errorlog "logs/error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" common
    Alias /wedding "/var/www/html/xyz"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost abc.com.br:80>
    ServerAdmin email@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    ServerName abc.com.br
    Errorlog "logs/error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom, depois de várias tentativas e erro eu finalmente consegui!

A primeira coisa que fiz foi adicionar cada site em uma subpasta. A estrutura de diretórios ficou assim:

/var/www/html/abc

/var/www/html/xyz

Depois eu alterei o httpd.conf adicionando o código abaixo

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin email@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/xyz"
    ServerName xyz.com
    ServerAlias www.xyz.com
    Errorlog "logs/error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin email@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/abc"
    ServerName abc.com
    ServerAlias www.abc.com
    Errorlog "logs/error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

#DocumentRoot "/var/www/html" Importante comentar essa linha!
```

Por fim, na tela de configuração de cada wordpress eu coloquei a url do wordpress e a url do site o respectivo domínio
www.abc.com.br e www.xyz.com.br